# How to unit test private properties?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm pretty new to TDD and I have a hard time to understand how to test private members of the class *(I know! It's private, shouldn't be tested - but please keep reading)*. We might have a public function which sets private property and other public function that returns "something" based on that private property.

Let me show you a basic example:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    private Cell[,] Cells { get; }
    public Table(Cell[,] cells)
    {
        Cells = cells;
    }

    public void SetCell(int x, int y, string value)
    {
        Cells[x, y].Value = value;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Cells.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Cells.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Cells[i, j].Value = "";
            }
        }
    }

    public bool AreNeighborCellsSet(int x, int y)
    {
        bool areNeighborCellsSet = false;

        // checking...

        return areNeighborCellsSet;
    }
}
```

In this example `Cells` are private, because there's no reason to make them public. I don't need to know what's the value of particular `Cell` outside this class. I just need an information if neighbor cells are empty.

**1. How can I test `Reset` method?**

Technically I should create a Table with mocked array of cells. Call `Reset` and then assert if every cell has empty `Value`. But I can't actually check if they are empty or not.

**2. In this case I would call `Assert` many times (for every cell) - is it a good practice? I've read that "It's not!", but Reset resets all cells, so I have to somehow check every cell.**

EDIT:
Option 2:

```
public class Table
{
    private Cell[,] Cells { get; }

    public Table(int height, int width, ICellFactory cellFactory)
    {
        Cells = new ICell[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < Cells.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Cells.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Cells[i, j].Value = cellFactory.Create(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    // Rest is the same...
}
```

Comment: That what happens when you don't follow SOLID principles in design ;)

Comment: @Zegar why? what's wrong? Which SOLID principle is vaioleted?

Comment: @LouisaBickley, poor design aside, yes you can check cells. just hold on to the cells passed into the table  constructor and inspect it after calling method under test.

Comment: Don't use any private properties/methods in tests. They are implementation details. You use a `Cell[,]` now, but you might change it to a different data structure later. Well written unit tests should work after such changes. In your case you can easily use `AreNeighborCellsSet` method to check if all cells are empty. It's fine to use multiple asserts as long as they logically check one thing.

Comment: @Nkosi hmm.. but which principle is vaioleted? my other approach was to inject a CellFactory into Table's constructor and create the array in the constructor.

Comment: @Louisa Bickley Basically there is no need to check if loop iterates through whole collection. That is tested by the framework team in MS. What you need to do is to test if your new type (in this case Cell) behaves properly. Write separate tests for Cell class checking if after setting the value to null value remains null.

As for the design - in my opinion you're violating the SRP.

Just add method Reset to the cell and call it in the loop in Table class for every cell.

Comment: @Zegar How does the public interface of `Table` tells you there is any `for` loop? What if the implementation is changed to store a collection of set `Cell`s (which would be a reasonable implementation if only few cells are set in a large table)?

Answer (score 3):

Your class have three public methods

```
void SetCell
void Reset
bool AreNeighborCellsSet
```

So all functionality should be tested only through those methods and with possible help of constructor input arguments.

I am afraid you are not doing TDD, because you are trying to test already implemented logic (`for` loop of internal member). With TDD you should write unit tests by using only public API of class under test.

When you test `Reset` method you should think how it affect on results of other public methods. `Table` class has only one method which return some value we can observe - `bool AreNeighborCellsSet` - so seems like this is the only method against which we can execute our asserts.

For `Reset` method you need to set cells so that `AreNeighborCellsSet` returns `true`. Then execute `Reset` and assert that now `AreNeighborCellsSet` returns false.

```
[Test]
public void AfterResetGivenCellShouldNotHaveNeighbors()
{
    // Arrange
    var cell = new Cell { X = 1, Y = 1, Value = "central" };
    var neighborCell = new new Cell { X = 1, Y = 2, Value = "neighbor" };
    var table = new Table(new[] { cell, neighborCell });

    // table.AreNeighborCellsSet(cell.X, cell.Y) - should return true at this moment
    // Act
    table.Reset();

    // Assert
    table.AreNeighborCellsSet(cell.X, cell.Y).Should().BeFalse();
}
```

This is a good example of TDD (Test-Driven Development), where problems with testing is good sign that something wrong with design.

Actually, I think, in your case you don't need `Reset` method at all - just create a new instance of `Table` every time you need to reset it.

Comment: Thanks, that would mean that I could go with "Option 2" (which was my first option actually) and inject `cellFactory` into `Table` and create new cells upon Reset. I thought that reseting `value` to empty is faster.. Idk why

Comment: I prefer to create new instance of `Table` every time you want to reset it. With creation of new instance logic of `Table` will be more predictable

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Ignas my be a workaround for the problem but I feel a need to clarify some design issues here:

Basically there is no need to check if loop iterates through whole collection. That is tested by the framework team in MS. 
What you need to do is to check if your new type (in this case `Cell`) behaves properly.

In my opinion you're violating the SRP. There is really no need for `Table` class to know how to reset this particular implementation of `Cell`. If some day you decide to create a cell able to contain a picture let's say, you'll most likely feel a need to clear it in some other way than by setting an empty string to it's `Value` property.

Start with abstracting `Cell` to an interface. Then just add method `Reset()` to the `Cell` and call it in the loop in Table class for every cell.

That would allow you to create tests for your implementation of `Cell` and there you can check if after calling `Reset()` cell's value truly becomes null or empty or whatever you need :-)

Comment: Thanks, Reset function in Cell makes A LOT of sense. I'll do that. But the main problem still remains...  I think. How about other functions that manipulates private Array?

How about SetCell or how about a function "SetRandomCell" (which basically sets a random item from the table)?

Comment: @LouisaBickley Deal with them in exactly the same way. For example `SetCell` method shouldn't play with the cell's value itself but use some public setter or public method `SetValue()` of the `Cell`.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to test private properties with no need for changing your code or adding extra code to your tested class, you can use testing tools that allows you to do so.
for example i used Typemock to change the logic of the Table c'tor to create a populated table and to get the private property Cells after calling the reset method:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var handle = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<Table>(Members.CallOriginal, context =>
    {
        var tempcells = context.Parameters[0] as Cell[,];

        for (int i = 0; i < tempcells.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tempcells.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                tempcells[i, j] = cellFactory.Create(i, j);
            }
        }
        context.Parameters[0] = tempcells;

        //calling the original ctor with tempcells as the parameter
        context.WillCallOriginal();
    });

    // calling the ctor with the custom logic
    var testTable = new Table(new Cell[2,2]);


    testTable.Reset();
    // calling the private property
    var resTable = Isolate.Invoke.Method(testTable, "get_Cells") as Cell[,];

    // for asserting
    var emptyCell = new Cell { Value = string.Empty };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(emptyCell.Value, resTable[i, j].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zegar mentioned in comments there could be several code design considerations, and probably writing tests first aka using TDD would help not to even run into such situations, however I think there is a simple workaround as well.

- You are passing array as **reference** into `Table` class and not overriding it, therefore you can access the array outside of `Table` class even though you are modifying it inside the class.
- You don't need to do many asserts, you just need to arrange an expected array for assertion. Use `FluentAssertions` and specifically `ShouldBeEquivalentTo()` which is a very nice solution for arrays comparison. [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/).

Sample test below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedCells = new Cell[2, 2];
        expectedCells[0, 0] = new Cell { Value = string.Empty };
        expectedCells[0, 1] = new Cell { Value = string.Empty };
        expectedCells[1, 0] = new Cell { Value = string.Empty };
        expectedCells[1, 1] = new Cell { Value = string.Empty };

        var cells = new Cell[2,2];
        cells[0,0] = new Cell { Value = "00" };
        cells[0,1] = new Cell { Value = "01" };
        cells[1,0] = new Cell { Value = "10" };
        cells[1,1] = new Cell { Value = "11" };
        var table = new Table(cells);

        // Act
        table.Reset();

        // Assert
        cells.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedCells); // using FluentAssertions 
    }
```

To summarize and answer your questions.

1. Test `cells` array you pass into the constructor.
2. Ideally you want to have a single assert per test, if possible.

Comment: Your test relies on implementation details of the tested class. Even worse - it relies on a possible bug (not making a copy of the array is a bug unless it's well-documented).

Comment: It's a bad one, completely unmaintainable. You don't even need workarounds to test this method - checking if `AreNeighborCellsSet` is false for all cells seems enough.

Comment: @JakubLortz I don't know Jakub.. It doesn't sound good to test just a portion of results. But I'm just a beginner, so probably I'm wrong :) It's just doesn't sounds good

Comment: @LouisaBickley Does `AreNeighborCellsSet` check if ANY neighboring cells are set? If yes then you can use it to assert that none of the cells are set. If it checks if ALL neighboring cells are set, it gets more complicated. You can still test it, although not by simply calling `Reset` and checking the state (you'd have to set some cells after resetting the table, then check the state). Remember that the point of unit tests is to let you be confident that you don't break your code when you modify it. If you rely on implementation details, any change in production code will break the tests too.

Comment: @JakubLortz I came up with such approach: I added `Reset` method to the `Cell`. And tested it there. For board I'm calling Cell.Reset in the loop. I mocked `Cell` and in `Board.Reset` I'm checking if `Cell.Reset` was called. What do you think?